# Non toxic low melting point alloy

Tags: toxicology

I am looking for an alloy with low melting temperature (< 350°C) which is not toxic when in direct constant contact with skin, food and overall in domestic environment. My application is a solder that can be used for soldering a ring.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a metallurgist, which you should probably ask... but there is this that I found:

[Low Melting Fusible Alloys](http://www.rotometals.com/Low-Melting-Fusible-Alloys-s/21.htm)

Both Cadmium and Lead are toxic, but Bismuth, Indium, and Tin are not. An alloy of those might be what you're looking for. Indium raises the price-point considerably, as it's a few magnitudes more expensive than Bismuth and Tin.

Comment: Metallurgist will most probably tell that toxicity is for biologist or toxicologist and there is no stackexchange for metallurgist yet

Comment: Rather than a metallurgist I would probably ask a jeweler... they should definitely know what they are allowed to use.

Comment: @nico: just tried contacting jewelers, though not sure if they use low melting point alloys

Comment: @tig: right, did not think about that